# Is there a stochastic domination between "sub"Bernoulli random variables and Bernoulli ones?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given an $n$-element set $[n]$. Let $R$ be a random subset of $[n]$, whose distribution is unknown, especially we do not assume independence in it. But what we know is that for all subsets $S\subseteq [n]$ and for some $0<p<1$
$$P(S\subseteq R)\le p^{|S|}.$$

Let $X=Ber(n,p)$. Is it true that for any $x>0$
$$P(|R|\ge x)\le P(X\ge x)?$$

If the above is true, furthermore, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of deterministic $k$-subsets of $[n]$. Is it true that for any $x>0$
$$P(|\{F\in \mathcal{F}:F\subseteq R\}|\ge x)\le P(|\{F\in \mathcal{F}:F\subseteq X\}|\ge x)?$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but what is $I$? You have an unknown underlying distribution on subsets of $[n]$, so is $I$ a random variable following this distribution (i.e. $R$)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It should be $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition would be that it's false because applying a simple union bound on $\mathbb{P}[|R|\ge x]$ gives an upper bound of $\binom{n}{x}p^x$ which looks meaningless in order to compare it to tails of binomials.

I suggest the following distribution: $\{1\}$ with probability $1/2$ and $\{2\}$ with probability $1/2$. It satisfies the property for $p=1/2$ but $\mathbb{P}[|R|\ge 1]=1$

Comment: What if we assume the independence in $R$, say $P(S_1\cup S_2\subseteq R)=P(S_1\subseteq R)P(S_2\subseteq R)$ for all disjoint $S_1,S_2\subseteq [n]$? Will we have the stochastic domination result?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword that you are looking for is *stochastic domination*.

In general, the answer is no for general Bernoulli random fields (short BRF).

For Bernoulli product fields (short BPF), as asked in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523787/is-there-a-stochastic-domination-between-subbernoulli-random-variables-and-ber#comment7252214_3523820), the answer only depends on the ordering between the vectors of single variable marginals. The construction of a dominating coupling is  trivial for one variable. Independence makes  the product of the dominating single-variable couplings a dominating coupling between the products.

There is a nice example in "Domination by product measures" by Liggett, Schonmann & Stacey , giving a translation-invariant BRF on $\mathbb{Z}$ with marginal probability $1/2$ and both $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = \dotso = X_n = 1)\in{}o(1/(n!))$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = \dotso = X_n = 0)\in{}o(1/(n!))$. This means that it is neither dominated by a non-trivial BPF, nor dominates a non-trivial BPF.

For special kinds of BRFs there are some conditions known:

- Markov fields: see e.g. "Probability on Graphs" by Grimmett
- Fields with positive and negative association: see e.g. "Probability on Graphs" by Grimmett
- 1-dependent BRFs: see "Domination by product measures" by Liggett, Schonmann & Stacey